# SCNTransaction AnimationOptions

Tags: ios, swift, animation, scenekit

I have an animation in my SceneKit project. It animates the node that is pressed. Now, the animation works with this code:

```
SCNTransaction.begin()
SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
    SCNTransaction.setCompletionBlock {
        SCNTransaction.begin()
        SCNTransaction.setAnimationDuration(0.5)
        result.node!.position.y -= 1
        SCNTransaction.commit()
    }
    result.node!.position.y += 1
    SCNTransaction.commit()
}
```

I want to make the node seem like it is jumping, therefore I would like to use some animation options, such as you can use with a UIView: `CurveEaseIn` etc.. (I want it to start slowly, end abrupt. The second should be abrupt first, then slowly.)

Is there a way to use these for a `SCNTransaction`? Or is there maybe a better way to make it 'bounce'?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Changing the timing function

Yes, you can change the timing function with `SCNTransaction`.

You do that by creating a `CAMediaTimingFunction` object and assigning it using `setAnimationTimingFunction()`. There are a couple of named timing functions (for example "ease in"), or you can create one using two set of control points.

```
let easeIn = CAMediaTimingFunction(name: kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn)
SCNTransaction.setAnimationTimingFunction(easeIn)
```

## Using a key-frame animation

Another alternative is to create a more custom key-frame animation for the node's y-position. I did a bounce looking key-frame animation in [the sample code for Chapter 5](https://github.com/d-ronnqvist/SCNBook-code/blob/master/Chapter%2005%20-%20Chess/Code/Chapter%2005%20-%20Chess/ChessView.m#L319) of [my book about Scene Kit](http://scenekitbook.com):

```
var jump = CAKeyframeAnimation(keyPath: "position.y")

let easeIn  = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.35, 0.0, 1.0,  1.0)
let easeOut = CAMediaTimingFunction(controlPoints: 0.0,  1.0, 0.65, 1.0)

jump.values   = [0.000000, 0.433333, 0.000000, 0.124444, 0.000000, 0.035111, 0.000000];
jump.keyTimes = [0.000000, 0.255319, 0.531915, 0.680851, 0.829788, 0.914894, 1.000000];
jump.timingFunctions = [easeOut,  easeIn,  easeOut,  easeIn,   easeOut,   easeIn  ];
jump.duration = 0.783333;

yourNodeThatWasClicked.addAnimation(jump, forKey: "jump and bounce")
```

If you go down this path, I would recommend finding somewhere that you can experiment, tweak, and play with the key times and values of the key-frame animation. Perhaps a playground or a small custom app with sliders where you can get fast iterations.

Comment: I figured one improvement I wanted to share with you: instead of setting the values to *0.0001* etc. you might want to do `result.node.position.y+0.0001` since this will make it bounce from the position the node is on right now instead of starting from y=0. :)

Comment: @LinusG. You could also configure the animation to be `additive`.

Comment: Hey one more question. I display a view on top of the node. Can I move the view with the same animation somehow so it looks like it sticks together? I tried to simply do `view.addAnimation(jump, forKey: "jump and bounce")` but that (of course) does not work...

Comment: You can add it to the view's layer.

Comment: Add what to which layer? :D

Comment: Add the animation object to the view's layer if you want to animate the view using the same animation.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `CABasicAnimation` with `byValue` of `1` and set `autoreverses` to `YES`. Finally set its `timingFunction` to `kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseIn` (or, more specifically, a timing function initialized with this curve name).

Comment: Is there anything similar to SCNTransaction in SpriteKit?